# Giving the Facebook like button a variable width?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-like

I'd like to right align the Facebook like button, so that regardless of whether 0 or 10,000,000 people have liked it it lines up with the right side of the page.  Is this possible??  I've looked everywhere to no avail.

Thanks for helping!

This is what we're looking to do, but right now we have to set a fixed width on the like button, so if the like count is 1 - the page isn't aligned properly, or if the like count is 250 the page isn't aligned properly.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Walker, Have you found solution? I want to do this recently, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the facebook button inside a div, and set the div overflow hidden, just to make sure that it wont exceed the fixed width.

```
.mybutton{
    width:50px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

You can see this jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/62sCG/1/

Comment: I edited my original question to have some more details, this is sort of on the right track but wouldn't this cut the like count off/have too much space depending on how many people have liked the page?

Comment: @Walker, I'm not sure if i understood your question fully, but you want to display the 'button_count' (the horizontal button with count', as shown in your image. You can set some default width for the button eg. 450px, it shouldn't create any alignment problem?

Comment: I can set a fixed width for the button, but I need the contents to right align - or there will be a massive gap between the like button and the edge of the page.